# How would a Brit say this in a formal letter?

Tags: british-english, formal-language

English is not my main language, but I'm quite a perfectionist so I always 
try to improve it.

In a recent message to a British coworker, I've written the following 
sentence:

> The delivery record shows that the aforementioned shipment to
>   (addressee's  address), was collected by the addressee after being
>   identified by means of ID card on (date) at (time) from the (road
>   name) Post Office, (place).

I don't know why, but the 2nd half of the sentence, starting from "*after 
being identified...*" doesn't sound too good in my head.
How would you say it in British English?

Answer (score 1):

Even as a British person, I find your text quite verbose (and extremely formal, perhaps too formal for a coworker). I would shorten it to:

> According to records, the delivery to [address] was collected by the addressee at [place] at [time] on [date] after providing proof of identity in the form of an ID card.

If you'd rather stick with your original syntax, here are some minor suggestions:

- If the address is short, don't put a comma before "was", since there's no natural pause there;
- "after being identified by means of ID card" is not a usual way of speaking. Try "after their identity was confirmed by checking their ID card".
- "after being identified" obviously refers to the person here, but to me this sentence parses the *shipment* having its identity validated ("[the shipment was [collected by the addressee after being] identified]"). Try to rearrange the sentence so that logical parts come together, or add "their" somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> The delivery record shows that the aforementioned shipment to
>   (addressee's address), was collected by the addressee after being
>   identified by means of ID card on (date) at (time) from the (road
>   name) Post Office, (place).

You could recast in the active voice:

**The delivery record indicates that addressee presented an ID card and collected the aforementioned shipment from the ____ post office at (time) on (date).**